# view all the subclass of UIView or NSObject

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiview

You can view the Java API in tree structure. So you can view all the subclasses of Object.

How would I  view all the subclasses of UIView or NSObject IPhone Cocoa API?

I just found out you can do this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

searchBar is subclass of UIView. I want to add a textField to a tableView. I wonder if there is a similar control,say inputbar, that subclasses UIView:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = inputBar;
```

This inputBar would do the same job the IPhone message app's input textField.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a class browser in Xcode that shows the complete (public) hierarchy. Easy way to see all the UIView subclasses.

Comment: Thanks very much.
xcode->project->class browser
or 
short cut shift+cmd+c

Answer (score 0):

There's a great class map in Xcode. Select Design -> Class Model -> Quick Model.

Comment: hi Ben:
Thanks very much for your help.The Quick model shows the class diagram of my own application. I am after the whole Cocoa API